# JQuery validation on inner form (dialog)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-validate, jquery-ui-dialog

I've a jsp with a `form` that include another jsp with a `div` (that's a JQuery dialog) and in the dialog I've a form that I've to validate.

My issue is: I cannot create an inner form opened in a dialog. So when I try to validate it, I get following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'form' of undefined`.

See following snippet, please:

```html
<html>
<head>  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="extForm">
    <div id="myDialog">
      <form id="intForm">
        <label for="field1">Don't write anything in textbox, just click the button</label>
        <input type="text" id="field1" required>
      </form>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
<script>
  $("#myDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "myDialog",
    buttons: {
      "Click me": function(){
        $("#myDialog form").valid();
      }
    }
  });
  $("#myDialog").dialog("open");
</script>
</html>
```

If I remove the external form, it works fine. I can I solve this? Thanks.

**Note:** I can't remove the external form and I have to validate only the fields inside my dialog.

Comment: You have a `form` within a `form` which is invalid HTML.  The plugin also will not work in this scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved wrapping dialog inside a form, using option create:

> create: function(){
>         formDialog = $(this).wrap($('')).parent();
>       }

This is the result:

```html
<html>
<head>  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.validation/1.15.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="extForm">
    <div id="myDialog">
        <label for="field1">Don't write anything in textbox, just click the button</label>
        <input type="text" id="field1" required>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
<script>
  var formDialog;
  $("#myDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    title: "myDialog",
    create: function(){
      formDialog = $(this).wrap($('<form>')).parent();
    },
    buttons: {
      "Click me": function(){
        formDialog.valid();
      }
    }
  });
  $("#myDialog").dialog("open");
</script>
</html>
```

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting that error because when you call `$("#myDialog").dialog()` function of jQuery, myDialog div loses the form from it's inner html.

Please put html back after dialog and before open dialog functions

e.x.

```
<script>
    $("#myDialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        title: "myDialog",
        buttons: {
            "Click me": function(){
                $("#myDialog form").valid();
            }
        }
    });

$("#myDialog").html("<form id='intForm'><label for='field1'>Don\'t write anything in textbox, just click the button</label><input type='text' id='field1' required></form>");

    $("#myDialog").dialog("open");
</script>
```

This code should run fine!

Thank you

Comment: I don't like too much the `html` inside javascript, anyway I voted up for the effort. Thank you. I solved using `wrap` as you can see in my answer.